# Is greedy layer-wise pretraining obsolete?

Tags: neural-networks

I was looking into the use of a greedy layer-wise pretraining to initialize the weights of my network.

Just for the sake of clarity: I'm referring to the use of gradually deeper and deeper autoencoders to teach the network gradually more abstract representations of the input one layer at the time.

However, reading [**HERE**](https://machinelearningmastery.com/greedy-layer-wise-pretraining-tutorial/), I read:

> Nevertheless, it is likely better performance may be achieved using modern methods such as better activation functions, weight initialization, variants of gradient descent, and regularization methods.

and

> Today, we now know that greedy layer-wise pretraining is not required to train fully connected deep architectures, but the unsupervised pretraining approach was the first method to succeed.

My question is then: if I'm building a network already using "*modern*" techniques, such as ReLU activations, batch normalization, adam optimizers, etc, is the good-ol' greedy layer-wise pretraining useless? Or can it still provide an edge in the initialization of the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. It could give you a boost or it could not.

Intuitively I would expect it to actually hurt performance if the network is initialized correctly (I think the optimizer is less of a bottleneck because they will have the same effect in both approaches).

**Ideal World:** We optimize the network as a whole to gain better course grained features over the sequential layers of the encoder

**Reality years ago:** Deep nets have trouble in information propagation either forward or backwards (ex: vanishing/exploding activation and vanishing/exploding gradient).

- **solution:** Break up the training into iterative schemes that don't require backward information to propagate far at each optimization step

  - **Cons:** Each step is looking for a greedy solution, rather than a deep one.

**Reality today:** Depending on the domain, there are various publications discussing how to circumvent this issue (ex: Residual networks, He initialization, fixup initialization, batchnorms, different activation functions, etc...)

- **solution:** We can train deep AEs without sequential layerwise training and achieve usually better results, because the model and optimization scheme allow for deep representations to form.

I hope this  helped give some form of intuition of the matter.